# Who is this physical fitness trainer?

Tags: bodybuilding, training

[image]

Help me to find his name please ! Thank in advance Physical Fitness users !

Comment: Welcome to the Fitness SE! Unfortunately, this type of questions is off-topic here, as you'll find in the Help Center. But as David has already said, this guy's name is Mike Rashid. You can find his YouTube channel [here](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCHp-_faz2gINcwGEf9A6ZZg).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

His name is Mike Rashid. [Here's the video that still appears to be taken from.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I_9SPjhoJ9o)